# Post JSON data from JSP using Javascript, AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring

I want to post JSON data from JSP to Spring MVC Controller. For this, I am using Javascript Ajax. Please help me on this. I searched on net but could not get the solution for my problem.

When I execute the code I get bellow error:

> Parse Error: Incorrect syntax Error Unexpected End of Input`and some Ids get printed in a console as below:`person@35fcfbc0, person@35fcfbc5`

But I want the value of `data1`, `data2` and `data3` to be printed in console;
My Json String as below

```
{“persons”:
    [
    {“data1”:”1000”, “data2”:”false”,”data3”:”Holiday”},
    {“data1”:”1000”, “data2”:”false”,”data3”:”Holiday”}
   ]
 }
```

I am using below Javascript and Ajax to post Data

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
  var sJson
  var ssJson
  function dataRow(value1,value2,value3)
  {
   this.data1 = value1;
   this.data2 = value2;
   this.data3 = value3;
  }
  $('#help_button2').click(function()
  {
   // create array to hold your data
   var dataArray = new Array();
   var Vars
   // iterate through rows of table
   // * Start from '2' to skip the header row *
   $(".case").each(function(i)
   {
    if (this.checked)
    {
     var Vars=i+1
     //alert("Checkbox at index " + Vars + " is checked.");

     var Vars1= $("#myTable tr:nth-child(" + Vars + ") td").eq(18).find('select').val()
     //alert(Vars1) 
     //alert(Vars)
     if (Vars1!="nooption")
     {

      dataArray.push
      (
       new dataRow
       (
        $("#myTable tr:nth-child(" + Vars + ") td").eq(1).html(),
        $("#myTable tr:nth-child(" + Vars + ") td").eq(18).find('select').val(),
        $("#myTable tr:nth-child(" + Vars + ") td").eq(19).find('select').val()
       )
      );
     } //else {alert("Please Select Option for Error_NoError ")
      //return false;
      //}
    }
   });

   ssJson1 = JSON.stringify({"persons" : dataArray });

   alert(ssJson) 
   alert(ssJson1)
   $.ajax({ 
    url:'<%=webUrl%>/data/data', 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data:ssJson1,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) { 
     alert(data.data1 + " " + data.data2 + " " + data.data3);
    },
    error:function(data,status,er) { 
     alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er+ssJson);
    }
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

My Pojo Class

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
private int data1;
private String data2;
private String data3;
public int getData1() {
    return data1;
}
public void setData1(int data1) {
    this.data1 = data1;
}
public String getData2() {
    return data2;
}
public void setData2(String data2) {
    this.data2 = data2;
}
public String getData3() {
    return data3;
}
public void setData3(String data3) {
    this.data3 = data3;
}
```

My Controller code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/data",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody void data(@RequestBody PersonList persons) throws 
  ParseException, IOException
  {
  List<Person> data1s=persons.getPersons();
  System.out.println(data1s);
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your posted json object is a valid?

Comment: Do you get parsing error if you correct the quotations signs in your json object?

Comment: Where would you like your data to be printed? On Java side, or on the JavaScript side?

Comment: Yes the Json object is valid and I get the parsing error even when i correct quotations  I want to print the values on Java side that is spring controller and then insert those values in SQL Database